# How to get n-1 records in descending order by joining two tables from phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables- "blogs" and "blog_categories". I want to fetch 5 records except for the last record from the "blogs" table (as the "blogs" table has all records and "blog_categories" have the primary key) from the n number of list in descending order according to the "blog_id" column which is in the "blogs" table. This is all I want for the phpmyadmin query.

I have tried a query for PHPMyAdmin as below, but it is not working-

`SELECT * FROM blogs INNER JOIN blog_categories ON blogs.blog_category = blog_categories.category_id WHERE blogs.blog_category ='1' ORDER BY blogs.blog_category, blogs.blog_posting_date DESC LIMIT n-1;`

In the "**LIMIT**" clause "**n**" it shows an error-

"**Unexpected token. (near n)**"

Comment: you want 5 records? 4 records? it is not clear what you actually want. It would be clear if you supplied some sample data, then, supply the expected result. This way you aren't solely dependent on words to explain the requirements.

Comment: I have n number of records

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just need a user variable, like this:

```
SET @n = 5;

SELECT *
FROM blogs
INNER JOIN blog_categories ON blogs.blog_category = blog_categories.category_id
WHERE blogs.blog_category ='1'
ORDER BY blogs.blog_category, blogs.blog_posting_date DESC
LIMIT @n-1;
```